# JMS strange problem

Tags: java, jms, messaging, deserialization

I have a problem in a system where ~500 servers are communicating with central server through JMS over ~1000 topics. It's a 10 year old system and it worked good until few months ago.

In the last 3 months I had these types of errors:

- central server can't deserialize Integer because Integer in the message has wrong SerialVersionID

  > Deserialize message failed. - cause: java.io.InvalidClassException: java.lang.Integer; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1360651450463909473, local class serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920
- central server can't deserialize unknown class

  > Deserialize message failed. - cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: javnteger.Integer
- JMS tries to instantiate Number class which is abstract

  > Caught JVM Error: java.lang.InstantiationError: java.lang.Number

For all errors problem is localized in one random topic. If messages from that topic are deleted and sent again from servers everything went ok.

I'm suspecting JMS hardware. HDD is ok. We need to test memory and I don't know where to look next.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: The second deserialize error, did you munge the copy/paste or does it really reference a class called javnteger.Integer?

Comment: This *really* smells like JVM version mismatches between your different servers. Like Damokles said, have their been any JVM upgrades done to any servers in your park lately? Also, point 2 (if it's indeed supposed to be javnteger.Integer) looks like a typical IDE induced error. Someone wrote code that was supposed to use java.lang.Integer, but accidentally imported this other javnteger.Integer class, which is not known to the receiving server.

Comment: All JVMs are the same. I didn't munge the copy/paste. Nobody uses javnteger.Integer because code is the same on all servers. It looks like I have some "noise" in transferring bytes :)

Comment: Any chance one (or more) of the clients implemented some sketchy runtime byte code instrumentation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a JVM issue. Back at least as far as JDK 1.2 (actually back to 1.0.2 if you believe the comment in the java.lang.Integer source distributed with the JDK), Integer's serialVersionUID has been "1360826667806852920L", which matches your "local class" version. They've never changed it in order to preserve backward compatibility. That fact combined with the "ClassNotFoundException: javnteger.Integer" (should be java.lang.Integer) points unmistakably to data corruption. Either a sender, a receiver, or the network itself is corrupting messages. Bad RAM would seem a likely culprit, especially if it's only intermittent and seldom. If it were the network, it would probably happen more often and be less predictable.